# How to do '@somename' like twitter functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter, autocomplete

I am trying to do a functionality like which happens on Twitter. 
If I write @J in text box, a list should appear show with autocomplete starting names "Javascript", "Java", "JQuery".

When I select Jquery, it should display in a `TextBox`. I got the autocomplete code from [Jquery](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1). But I am unable to do this '@' functionality.

Below is the code which I have done till now:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>autocomplete demo</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>  


            </head>
            <body> 
                <label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
                <input id="autocomplete"> 
                    <script>
var tags = [ "Javascript", "Jquery", "Java" ];
document.getElementById('autocomplete').onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 64 ) {        

            $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
                }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    };



                    </script> 
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Where's the code you've been working?

Comment: @aldrin27 I have added the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gtnf41co/5/

It checks input value starts with @:

```
if (this.value.search("@") == 0)
```

then takes out the @ in the request term

```
request.term.replace("@", "")
```

Comment: thanks for your code, but my output should be like I have to first enter the "@" and then "J", onkeypress of "@" symbol nothing should happened, when I keypress "J" all the words which starts with "J" should display. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok, and if typing @J you do not want to show the @ before each suggestion?

Comment: Yes, that was my client requirement :\

Comment: Then I think it's better when user is typing to get the input string. Only if it starts with @  show the suggestions

Comment: Thanks brother, You are a lifesaver..

Comment: ur welcome.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the autocomplete functionality by adding the @ symbol to your tags:

```
<script>
var tags = [ "@Javascript", "@Jquery", "@Java" ];

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: tags      
});
</script>
```

Comment: I wish my client would accept that.